# Get all phase job Build Numbers from a Multiphase Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins

I have created a multiphase Jenkins job where a total of 3 phases are added. All 3 phases run the robot framework tests. Now at the end of Jenkins job completion, I need to aggregate the results from all 3 jobs, which can be done using the output.xml generated by all 3 jobs.

But I need to get the build number of all 3 jobs at the end of execution, I have tried using the predefined parameter option[$<build_number_BUILD_NUMBER] for each build, also tried using the Jenkins API `http://<jenkins_url>/job/<build_numer>/lastBuild/buildNumber` but somehow bot of these options are not working for me.

Can someone suggest the best possible way to get the build numbers from the multiphase job so that the results can be aggregated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build numbers can be found using permalinks generated by Jenkins. Had to add a PostBuild Task plugin to get the build number and added a script to get the build number and merge the reports. The build number can be retrieved using:

```
jobnumber=$(cat ../../jobs/<build_name>/builds/permalinks | grep lastCompletedBuild | sed 's/lastCompletedBuild //')
```